# How to make iterator behave like a type through it iterates?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I want to iterate through a vector of stirngs and compare all inputs with a  value. So I've created this construction:

```
for (vector<string>::const_iterator i = needle.begin(); i != needle.end(); ++i) {         
            cout << *i << " ";

        }
```

Printing works all right, but I want to be able to access `std::string` functions, ie `find`
So while I'm able to write `needle[index].find("sampleString");` I want to be able to make iterator behave similar to this. So how to make something like `*i.find("sampleString");` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're almost there, but the operator precedence means that `*i.find()` doesn't work. It tries to dereference `i.find()`, rather than dereferencing `i` then calling `find` on the result. Use whichever of these looks nicest to you:

```
(*i).find("sampleString");
i->find("sampleString");
```

Comment: but why then this code `for (vector<string>::const_iterator i = needle.begin(); i != needle.end(); ++i) {         
            cout << i->find("hello world!") << " ";            
        }` , where needle vector holds 5 values, prints out this output? `4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 4294967295 
`

Comment: @Dworza: Because none of the strings contain `"hello world!"`, and so `find` returns `std::string::npos`, which is a large integer value. If any string did contain what you're looking for, you'd get a smaller number instead, indicating where in the string it was found. I've no idea why you get more than 5 numbers printed; presumably, it doesn't actually hold 5 values, but I can't tell without seeing how you populated it. If you've got questions about how `find` works, or why your vector doesn't have the expected contents, then ask them as new questions.

Comment: Uh...yea...my bad.. I wanted to compare it vice versa.. But this doesn't solve that issue,that I get so many values :-S Like for input:`"hello","world","rld","ell","hell"` that I want to compare with `"hello wordl!"`, I get output `0 6 8 1 0 0 6 8 1 0 0 6 8 1 0 0 6 8 1 0 `

Comment: @Dworza: If you have a question about why your vector doesn't seem to contain what you think it should, then ask a separate question, posting enough code to demonstrate what you're doing. These comments aren't the place for answering extra questions.